# Cannot build Shopware 6 admin with npm 8.11

Tags: npm, eslint, shopware6

When running `bin/build-administration.sh` we get

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.2.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@7.10.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"7.10.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"5.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   14 more (@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils, eslint-utils, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
npm ERR!   dev eslint-config-airbnb-base@"13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   eslint-config-airbnb-base@"^13.2.0" from @shopware-ag/eslint-config-base@1.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@shopware-ag/eslint-config-base
npm ERR!     @shopware-ag/eslint-config-base@"1.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@5.16.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
npm ERR!     dev eslint-config-airbnb-base@"13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     eslint-config-airbnb-base@"^13.2.0" from @shopware-ag/eslint-config-base@1.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@shopware-ag/eslint-config-base
npm ERR!       @shopware-ag/eslint-config-base@"1.0.0" from the root project
```

We are using this versions:

```
$ npm -v
8.11.0
$ node -v
v16.15.1
```

and Shopware 6.4.11.1

With npm 8.5 it seemed to work.

I am wondering if this is a bug in Shopware or in npm?

I would guess something needs to be updated in Shopware?

Comment: There is https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-20107 which seems to be another issue

Comment: see also https://github.com/shopware/production/issues/136

Answer (score 6, accepted):

run `npm config set legacy-peer-deps=true` in your project folder

this is related to https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4664